# What is the appropriate response of someone outside Israel during a war?

Tags: chutz-laaretz, army-military-war, current-events, state-of-israel

During a war or large scale military operation what are some of the best things for a person living in chutz l'arertz to do? Is saying tehillim and doing extra chesed enough? Should a person run to Israel and join the effort? Is there a middle ground?

Sourced answers *only*, please.

Comment: Shouldn't you do whatever you can?

Comment: @DoubleAA does that mean quit my job and join the IDF? Is that a chiyuv?

Comment: By the time you were trained enough to do anything helpful, the war will probably be over and then we'd have another jobless poor person on our hands. (Not to mention I don't know your age and health.) Do whatever you can that is helpful based on your situation. Everyone is different.

Comment: @DoubleAA I imagine there has to be some da'as torah on this. I'm not saying I have to get a gun and fight but there should be some torahdik response

Comment: What part of doing lots of mitzvos is not a torahdik response?

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17491/what-is-the-jewish-view-on-creating-an-army-to-defend-ourselves-against-armies

Comment: I think @DoubleAA is 100% correct. The best thing you can do is Daven, learn, do Hesed and get close to Hashem.

Answer (score 3):

Sotah 46a-b

[image]

[image]

also the rambam melachim 5-1:[image]

Answer (score 1):

The worst thing to do is nothing, as it is written in bechukotai: "If you will not hearken to Me, and walk casually with Me; I, too, will act casually with you..." (26:28)

Also, history shows that when there's problems in Israel, there's soon to be problems in chutz l'aretz. Maybe this will help stir a person in chutz l'aretz to examine his ways and repent.

see also
http://www.aish.com/h/iid/48951431.html

Comment: How does history show that?

Comment: for example, vietnam war during the arab wars in israel. huricane katrina around time of lebanon war. this last point is debatable, just my opinion

Comment: I think it's more like there are always problems both outside and inside Israel.

Answer (score 0):

As @doubleaa said in the comment on the OP.
 **you do what you can**

Source: I got it from [this video](https://youtu.be/fsADqkXyALk) (which might be a source by itself)

[sanhedrin 49](http://halakhah.com/sanhedrin/sanhedrin_49.html)

> This [view of Joab] is in contradiction to the view held by R. Abba b. Kahana, who said: **But for David,  Joab would not have succeeded in  war; and but for Joab, David could not have devoted himself to [the study of] the Torah**, for it is written, And David executed justice and righteousness for all his people, and Joab the son of Zeruiah was over the host:  — i.e., why was David able to execute 'justice and righteousness for all his people'? — Because 'Joab was over the host.' And why was 'Joab over the host'? — Because 'David executed justice and righteousness for all his people.'

See also Rashi on the posuk [Shmuel 2.8.15](http://www.chabad.org/15868#showrashi=true) ([link for sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_II_Samuel.8.14.1))

> **and David administered justice… and Joab the son of Zeruyah was over the host**.: David caused Joab to be successful over the host because he executed justice and charity, and Joab caused David to execute justice and charity because he would judge and Joab would enforce and chastise for him. Also, because Joab was engaged in the battles David was not busied with them, and was (lit., his heart was) left free to judge righteously.

[Another video](https://youtu.be/Dv7XUfPn1UA) of the Lubavicher Rebbe telling Jews in America what they should do when Isreal is at "war"

Comment: http://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma.5.5.2