# Have any Orthodox rabbis or rabbinic organizations called for a communal fast on Thursday, October 12, 2023?

Tags: fast-days, orthodox, current-events, organizations

In response to the current war in Israel, and the current situation (as I write this: hundreds of Israelis held hostage by terrorists, including children and the elderly), the organization [Hadar](https://hadar.org/) has called for a *ta'anit tzibbur* (a communal fast).  [The announcement of this communal fast](https://info.hadar.org/taanit-tzibbur?inf_contact_key=7fa5d8ae278f29bdc995f58fd5e7bacb680f8914173f9191b1c0223e68310bb1) says:

> Please join us this Thursday, October 12th, the 27th of Tishrei, for a
> communal fast day supported by rabbis and leaders from across the
> Jewish world. The fast will begin at dawn and end at nightfall.

I am curious about the phrase "supported by rabbis and leaders from across the Jewish world". Hadar is a progressive organization that promotes egalitarian interpretations of Jewish law, and for that reason alone I suspect many Orthodox rabbis would be reluctant to be associated with them, even on an issue that (arguably) ought to transcend such issues. On the other hand, few would argue against the basic premise, i.e.:

> We have a traditional practice for moments like this one: ta'anit
> tzibbur–a fast that draws in the entire community to unite for
> deliverance for those in crisis.

So I am interested: have any Orthodox rabbis, or rabbinic organizations (e.g. the RCA, OU, CRC, etc.) joined in this call?

(This question is obviously time-sensitive, and therefore I am unsure whether it is within the scope of the site. Apologies if it is inappropriate.  I'm also not sure what the appropriate tags are, so please feel free to edit.)

Comment: Relevant comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/137383/halacha-of-national-mourning#comment457985_137383

Comment: https://www.hidabroot.org/article/1186855

Comment: In reading over my own question, I hear two competing voices in my head: "*Chas v'shalom* that Jews should let denominational differences divide us at a time like this," and "*Chas v'shalom* that frum Jews should let progressive Jews dictate a communal response." Which voice is louder changes from moment to moment.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you for that link. If you have time, could you please write an answer with a translation of the relevant parts of that page?

Comment: @mweiss You forget that Israelis basically don't care about any of the Reform-Orthodox politics of the US. Those there that advocate fasting are simply not going to care one way or another what some random small "heretic" group in NY says or does.

Comment: @DoubleAA In that case perhaps the answer is "Orthodox rabbis in Israel have called for a *ta'anit tzibbur* for the same day, independent of the actions of Hadar."

Comment: Without regard to denominations, consider when it is permitted and when it is prohibited to declare a public fast (times of year), who has the authority to make such a call and for what circumstances in particular can they do it according to Jewish law.

Comment: @YaacovDeane could you expand on that comment into an answer?

Comment: Although belated, I came across this video from Rabbi David Bar Chaim of Machon Shilo in Israel who among other things discusses the subject of declaring communal fasts  outside of Eretz Yisrael, in contrast to inside Israel, in the current time. He states clearly that it is not done. https://youtu.be/MtaoN30hkDM?si=SOyeZ8pv36OPC0pb