# When to go out to fight the enemy?

Tags: sources-mekorot, army-military-war

I'm sure everyone knows what's going on right now in Eretz Yisrael with the rockets being fired at the Israeli population from Gaza and the response of the IDF.

I have heard many people say (charedim) that there is no need for the "Iron Dome" system that is in place to help shoot down in coming rockets and that there is no need to fight back. If we strengthen in limud haTorah then things will stop on their own.

While everyone agrees to strengthen in Limud HaTorah and Tefillah in order to bring more zechusim (merits) to the situation and that we trust HaShem will keep us safe. Still doesn't it speak about in Chazal and the Rambam about times when to go to war or fight back to save ones life (even going to battle on Shabbos.) However I'd like to have some source for this. Where are some examples (from Chazal or the Rambam or other writings) where they speak about the idea of going to battle (even on Shabbos) or that one should absolutely defend himself when attacked, etc.

Comment: A complete list of every mention of "going to battle, etc in Chazal and the Rambam (or any other sources.)"? Seriously? To what end on earth? And do you think you can possibly get a complete answer? Closing this as "overly broad... and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form".

Comment: וצ"ע http://i.stack.imgur.com/tdIvk.jpg

Comment: msh210 -- If I take out the world "all" will you re-open the question? I'm more and more confused at times by the purpose of this site and how they expect to further knowledge. If someone would write back with an answer that at least gives one or 2 sources that would surely be ok by me.

Comment: @msh210 -- Fixed, please re-open.

Answer (score 3):

The logic about not making an "Iron dome" could just as easily apply to going to the Doctor. Why go to the Doctor? Shouldn't someone just pray.

This is like the story from [Midrash Shmuel](http://www.schechter.edu/responsa.aspx?ID=32) about the sick person who came to Rabbi Ishmael and Rabbi Akiba and asked why should he go to the doctor instead of just praying to get better.

I do not agree with your premise that the iron dome is unnecessary.

However that said, Yaakov and Yishmael will always be opposed. The question is where the balance will hold. By davening and strengthening in service we can shift the balance. But we should complement that with physical actions as well.

Answer (score -2):

> When Yaakov was threatened with Esav and his 400 men ([Genesis 32](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8227/showrashi/true)), he responded in three ways (as noted by Rashi to verse 9):
>
> - He sent gifts.
> - He prayed.
> - He prepared for war.
>
> So yes, preparing for war certainly has a prominent place in Jewish ideology, right alongside diplomatic efforts and prayers to God. All three are important components of a proper defensive effort.

Borrowed from [@DoubleAA answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17503/1145) here.

Comment: Who gave this a down vote and why?

Comment: @Yehoshua, it doesn't seem to answer the question asked.

Comment: This is an exact copy of the answer you linked to.  Quoting other answers is fine, but you should try to add something to it to make this answer your own in some way.

Comment: @MonicaCellio -- If I find a Chasam Sofer that answers a question should I try and add something in order to make it my own!?!?

Comment: @MonicaCellio what about if the answer has all it needs, there is nothing to add? I dont agree that my answer does not deserve an upvote! But do what you want anyway.

Comment: @Yehoshua, yehuda, fair points.  (Though if the Chasam Sofer were a participant here I'd probably give him a chance to answer first.)  BTW, I haven't voted on this answer.

Comment: Grumble grumble. "Borrowed"? More like taken. Discourteous to take someone else's answer word for word. That's not research. Furthermore, I agree with @msh210: you don't even add a concluding statement about why you think it applies here as well as there.

Comment: @Monicacellio and msh210 surely know why I'm grumbling.

Comment: As does @double aa, unwitting "Mafkid" of this information.